# working with local variables and returning them in nested Common Lisp loops

Tags: common-lisp, nested-loops

I have the following code and the nested loop have an issue:
I aim to implement CLOS multi-dispatch (multi-methods) for academic purposes. I have a list of arguments passed to a generic function. The generic function (gf) contains a list of methods. In turn, each method in a generic function contains a list of classes (specializers) to which the arguments it operates on belong to. For a method to be applicable, each argument passed to the generic function must be an instance or subclass of its respective specializer in a method contained in the generic function's list of methods.  Particularly, working with local variables and returning them in nested loops is a problem.

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
     (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
                    do (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                              for arg in args
                               counting (instancep arg specializer) into matched_args
                                  )
         when (= matched_args (count args)
        collect method ) ))
```

Comment: there is no picture

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: `when (= matched_args (count args)` looks like it's missing a `)`.

Comment: What is the scope of matched_args?

Comment: Done a few edits to keep it bried. The 
when (= matched_args (count args) appears as it is in extended common lisp (read that here http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html). Bu there is something missing from this loop construct which I cannot tell. I would also like to ask, is args a list?

Comment: mathced_args is only mentioned for the first time here -->  counting (instancep arg specializer) into matched_args. I am for the idea it is instantiated here as a local variable visible to both the inner and outer loop. No?

Comment: And I believe `when (= matched_args (count args)
        collect method ) ))` should be `when (= matched_args (count args))
        collect method ))`

Comment: @khachik the last parenthesis is for closing the function compute-applicable-methods.

Comment: @Gakuo Irrelevant. The number of `)` has not changed.

Comment: @Gakuo The variable introduced by INTO is local to the enclosing LOOP. The LOOP macro is not designed to inspect the content of sub-expressions, it only looks for loop keywords directly inside its body, not the one inside nested LOOPs, so it cannot know it should declare and manage a variable for the inner matched_args accumulator. But, you can return values from one loop to another with "finally (return matched_args)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without proper indentation and code formatting you should write no code and also no Lisp code. With Lisp you also have no excuse, because the IDE will indent the code for you.

Indentation fixed:

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
  (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
        do (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                 for arg in args
                 counting (instancep arg specializer) into matched_args
                 )
        when (= matched_args (count args)
                collect method ) ))
```

Still the code is strangely formatted. Improvements:

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
  (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
        do (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                 for arg in args
                 counting (instancep arg specializer) into matched_args)
        when (= matched_args (count args)
                collect method)))
```

The first thing you can see that the function `=` isn't having a correct argument list. `collect` and `method` should not be arguments to `=`:

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
  (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
        do (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                 for arg in args
                 counting (instancep arg specializer) into matched-args)
        when (= matched-args (count args))
        collect method))
```

The inner `LOOP` does not return any value and you count into a local variable `matched-args`, which you don't use.

If you don't use the variable, let's remove it:

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
  (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
        do (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                 for arg in args
                 count (instancep arg specializer))
        when (= matched-args (count args))
        collect method))
```

Now the inner `LOOP` returns a value, but we don't use it. Improvement:

```
(defun compute-applicable-methods (gf &rest args)
  (loop for method in (generic-function-methods gf)
        for matched-args = (loop for specializer in (method-specializer method)
                                 for arg in args
                                 counting (instancep arg specializer))
        when (= matched-args (count args))
        collect method))
```

Comment: Very educative, Rainer! Nice to watch! :)